# How to make radio buttons horizontal inside fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Inside form I have two radio buttons like

```
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>
                    Choose a pet:
                </legend>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
                <label for="radio-choice-1"><img src="../static/images/Dog.png" />Dog</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
                <label for="radio-choice-2"><img src="../static/images/Cat.png" />Cat</label>
            </fieldset>
```

(I am using jquery mobile). How to make that those two buttons be horizontal and not vertical ( at the moment dog button is above cat and I need to be in one row ). How to make horizontal ?

Comment: Put the buttons into 2 div's and make the second one float:left. You can also use <pre> tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in fieldset

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
```

Source http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html

form this site verify the section **Horizontal radio button sets**